# How to use a EPM50S8 encoder?

Tags: localization, navigation

How can I use this encoder with my robot applications?

I couldn't find any tutorial about that and it has a lot of cables. (EPM50S8)

[image: Photo of EPM50S8 encoder]

I have read the datasheet but I don't understand the last three descriptions. What are these pins connected to on an Arduino?

[image: Cables listed in the datasheet]

Comment: Then please [edit] and add that info to your question to make it clearer what *exactly* you are unsure about. Please don't add additional info in the comments in a piece-meal fashion.

Comment: use any pins you like ... it is up to you to decide which pins you want to connect to the light blue and light purple wires ... the shield connects to the robot's frame

Comment: `has a lot of cables` ... i see lots of conductors, but only two cables

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [datasheet](https://www.eltron.pl/uploads/manufacturer_catalogs/1/10814/22_EPM50.pdf), you will see a number of example control I/O circuits.

For example:

[image: SSI Input]

[image: SSI Output]

[image: Parallel input and output]